# Action Controller: Exception caught in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue setting up this link at the bottom of my dashboard.

```
<%= link_to "Contracts", space_contract_path(@space, @contract), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here is my route path

```
space_contract GET /spaces/:space_id/contracts/:id(.:format) contracts#show
```

And here is my controller snippet

```
def dashboard
    @spaces = Space.where(prime_tenant_id: current_user.id)
    @properties = Property.where(landlord_id: current_user.id)
    @conversations = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per_page(25)
    @contracts = current_user.contracts
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Contracts", space_contract_path(@space,  @contract), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Or alternatively

```
<%= link_to "Contracts", [@space,@contract], class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

`@space` and `@contract` should be an instance of a resource e.g. in your controller

```
@space = Space.find(params[:space_id])
@contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: added the controller snippet